# Can I Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit) in hp compaq 6910p Notebook?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, 64-bit, hp

I am using windows xp in my hp compaq 6910p notebook. I want to migrate myself from windows to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system.
My notebook ram is 3GB (and virtual ram is 10GB for C drive where windows installed) but system architecture is x86.So that,

My question is Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(64 bit) in my system?
Please answer my question as soon as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). Yes, you can install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  64-bit on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at Ubuntu's minimum requirements:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

and compare those to the HP 6910P's specifications:

http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04142126.pdf

you'll see that yes, you can install Ubuntu 14.04 on the HP. That said, you'd do well to look around on the Internets to see if there are any known driver issues, bugs, etc.

Comment: off course, I already installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS system on my hp compaq 6910p model